# What's the formulation of N-point radix-N for NTT

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, finite-fields, transformation, fast-fourier-transform

We can write the formulation for the buttlerfly function applied in FFT as

\begin{align*}y_0 &= x_0 + x_1,\\
y_1 &= x_0 - x_1.
\end{align*}

As seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram).

For FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) we have that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are complex numbers, then the addition and subtraction operations are complex operations.

We can use the same formulation in NTT (Number Theoretic Transform), just replacing the complex operations by modular operations.

How to do the same conversion for radix-4 and radix-8, from FFT butterfly to NTT?

Comment: the radix-4 is obtained by chaining two stages radix-2.. and in the NTT $N | p-1$ so it is rarely a power of $2$ $\implies $ you have to derive the formula for the radix-$q$ for any $q$ (which is the same as for  the normal FT)

Comment: What you mean with "chaining two stages radix-2"?

Answer (score 1):

I could derivate the formula for radix-4 NTT following [this](http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/cml/dsp/training/coding/transform/fft.html).

In radix-4, each butterfly's element is given by

$$Y_{p,q} = \sum_{l=0}^3\left[W_N^{l\cdot q}X\left(l,q\right)\right]W_4^{l\cdot p}.$$

This way, let $P$ be the prime that generates the finite field used by NTT and $W_4$ and $WInv_4$ respectively it's twiddle factors for forward and inverse NTT. This way, the formulation of a radix-4 butterfly on forward NTT is

\begin{align*}
y_0 & = x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3,\\
y_1 & = x_0 + W_4\cdot x_1 - x_2 - W_4\cdot x_3, \\
y_2 & = x_0 - x_1 + x_2 - x3,\\
y_3 & = x_0 - W_4\cdot x_1 - x_2 + W_4\cdot x_3. 
\end{align*}

For inverse NTT we just replace $W_4$ by $WInv_4$.